# When to use and not to use each development paradigm?

Tags: language-agnostic, methodology, heuristics

Given the various methodical approaches to development, can we get some heuristics together on which ones are appropriate in what circumstances, e.g.

- case-driven development
- model-driven development
- behavior-driven development
- test-driven development
- Rational Unified Process
- Jackson Structured Design
- et al

No method is too old, specialized, or "out there" ;-)

Please list only one method per answer, and include the situations in which it is most appropriate and least appropriate. For example:

---

## Method

Hacking

## Most Appropriate

- When coding alone on something that doesn't really matter
- When experimenting to figure out how something *really* works, as opposed to:

  - how you think it works
  - the doc says it works
  - google says it works
  - it ought to work

## Least Appropriate

- When writing production code
- When working in a team environment

---

Note: Looking for specifics on each method, not general advice. Thank you.

Comment: judging from the upvotes and 'favorites' a few of us would like to know the answers to this question, but so far no one has any answers!

Comment: I'm surprised theres not more answers. I thought some people will be writing design patterns or at least give an example when to use procedural, functional and great example of OOPs

Comment: i am also surprised, but i guess this is sort of a poll question...

Answer (score 6):

Use the method that fits the way your team wants to work and gets the best results. Example: if your team is full of stored procedure, SQL-oriented table-thinkers, you shouldn't use an o/r mapper, because that is totally not fitting with how the team thinks/works.

And above all: get good software engineers. There's nothing more important than professional, good software engineers. With good software engineers, you can use any methodology and get good results.

Comment: Amen.  Good software engineers will do wonders for a project.

Comment: thanks, but i'm really looking for specifics on the available methods, not general advice

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you choose, make sure you question your approach regularly and improve it.

Comment: thanks, but i'm really looking for specifics on the available methods, not general advice